# Type constraint for module inclusion in OCaml

Tags: types, module, include, ocaml

I want to define the following module hierarchy, but it does not work :

```
module type A = sig
    type t
end

module type B = sig
    type u
    include A
end

module type C = sig
    (* Error: Unbound type constructor u *)
    include B with type t = u list
end
```

Why is there an error regarding type `u` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The types after the `=` should be available outside of the module you are trying to include/modify.

Here, you would do :

```
module type C = sig
  type u 
  include B with type u := u and type t = u list
end
```